# What is the best approach to sync two java projects?

Tags: java, git, maven, build, publish

I have two maven based java projects, project A and project B.
Project A is managed by a team and B by another team. Project A is a base project whose library and classes are consumed in project B.
Currently, Project A's team sends a jar of their project to team B whenever they make any change to their project and team B has to replace the old jar with the new one.

Since our projects are maven based projects and managed as git repositories, I believe that there will be a much better way to do it automatically, so that whenever there is a change in project A, team B need not to worry about it and the latest changes should automatically reflect to the team B.

Comment: Then do it.... (What is your question?)

Comment: You're using Maven. So Team A should publish to a local Maven repo and Team B should depend on that. No more manual copying of jar files.

Comment: You have answer in your question itself ! What exactly you are trying to say?

Comment: @dave I have a doubt in your approach, whenever team A will publish an update to the local repo, don't you think Team B has to update their pom.xml?

Comment: @NikunjAggarwal If the version number changes, then yes. But that's the case for any dependent library. On the plus side, this means you know which version you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you're using Maven, Team A should publish Project A to a repository (probably a private one). Team B and then depend on Project A (via their POM) and the rest will take care of itself, ie. no more manually copying of libraries.

As a bonus, Team B can always specify exactly which version of Project A they wish to depend on.

(Setting up your own private repository is not difficult. Apache's web server can host it or you can use a tool such as Nexus. Some build tools (eg. gradle) will generate a POM and publish your library to a site for you.)

Comment: You could improve this answer by elaborating a bit more on what you mean by "local repository". I assume that you're talking about a "managed repository" such as Nexus or Artifactory.

Answer (score -1):

Push the A Project(jar+pom) to some repository(Nexus). Then add the dependency in your Project B POM.xml with version as latest.

```
<distributionManagement> <repository> <id>releases</id> <name>Releases Repository</name> <url> http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases </url> </repository> <snapshotRepository> <id>snapshots</id> <name>Snapshot Repository</name> <url> http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots </url> </snapshotRepository> </distributionManagement>
```

Add the above in Project A and B

```
<dependency>
<groupId>mygroup</groupId>
<artifactId>C</artifactId></dependency>
```

in Project B add the above.
When a new change is done in Project A it is reflected in B while rebuilding.

[For more Maven](https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html)